# How do you remove an embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I've got a document that looks like this:

```
{listName: 'LoremIpsum'
 listItems: [{productDescription: "", productImage: ""}...]}
```

How would I go about deleting an item from listItems if productImage didn't exist?

I've tried the following with no result:

```
db.lists.update({"item.productImage":{$exists: false}}, {$unset:{"item":1}}, false, true )
```

Comment: Could you please update your original doc structure. because in your doc it was listitems.productimage and in your query it was item.productimage.. which one is right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $pull can contain element matching criteria. As such this single update will remove the items that do not contain the field "productImage" :

```
db.lists.update({}, {$pull:{listItems:{productImage:{$exists:false}}}}, false, true)
```

Comment: this works. just edit the command to update all documents. db.lists.update({}, {$pull:{listItems:{productImage:{$exists:false}}}},false,true)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't delete it in one step. But here's a two-step combination:

```
// unset matching array element. That'll leave null on its place
db.lists.update({"listItems.productImage":{$exists: false}}, 
                {$unset:{"listItems.$":1}});

// remove nulls from array
db.lists.update({listItems: null}, 
                {$pull: {listItems: null}});
```

Comment: Just tried this but it didn't work. Perhaps because it's actually an inner array?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [$pull operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull), which will remove everything with the matching criterion that you specify.

`db.lists.update({}, {"$pull": {"listItems" : {"productImage" : {$exists: false}} }})`