# Query Documents In Array

Tags: mongodb

I have one embedded MongoDB document and I need to remove `{nameofcontent:"miljox"}` from the below-mentioned document.

```
 {
   _id: 1,
   results: [
      { item: "A", score: 5, answers: [ { q:[{nameofcontent:"miljox"}]: 1, a: 4 }, { q:[{nameofcontent:"miljo"}], a: 6 } ] },
      { item: "B", score: 8, answers: [ { q:[{nameofcontent:"y"}], a: 8 }, { q: [{nameofcontent:"anil"}], a: 9 } ] }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you asking to just remove that content from the "inner" `"q"` or to `$pull` the "whole q" matching that field from the `"answers"` array? The first one you can reliably do. But the second fails on the positional `$` operator only being able to keep "one" index. The big lesson here should be. *"Do not nest arrays!"*.

Comment: If you are looking for something with pull, please take a look here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285766/how-do-you-remove-an-embedded-document-in-mongodb). and here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950451/remove-embedded-document-in-a-nested-array-of-documents). Hope this helps. Good luck